# Image not fitting inside Div

Tags: css

I have a container div (outer_most_container) that I want to place an image (blue gradient) in to serve as a background. The image should be fixed while scrolling. The problem right now is that the image is 1040 pixels in width and should fit accordingly to the width of the div of 65em but it is not.

Also, I'm not sure why the image disappears when zoomed out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/viSVp.png

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UnderWater Theme</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="underwater.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer_most_container">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="banner">    
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;       
}
.outer_most_container {
    position: relative; 
    width: 65em;
    height: 43.75em;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url('Aura.jpg');  
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use http://html5boilerplate.com/ which has a nice CSS reset instead of the general selector css reset you use here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent the image from resizing during zooming out by using:

```
background-size: 65em 43.75em;
```